# Deleting multiple rows based on row date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This [calendar's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14PdjAxYGFa5zL4j-oJQZVhfVBF1C5WLQyvrNRP5SxZ4/edit?usp=sharing) column A has dates as merged cells. The following script takes care of deleting previous days based on dates in column A:

```
function deleteRow_nedeles_plani() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Nedēļas plāni');
    var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-2;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
    {
          var row = data[i];
          var date = new Date();
          var sheetDate = new Date(row);
          var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0300','yyyy-MM-dd')
          var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0300', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
          if (Sdate.valueOf() > SsheetDate.valueOf())
          {
                sheet.deleteRow(i+3) //don't delete header
          }
         
    }
}
```

The problem that requires solving is getting to delete only the last previous day without affecting other rows or future days. The script works by unmerging the cells with a date and thus "thinks" there is only one row with a date and thus even the future days get crumbled as shown in this animagted gif -

[image]

Can someone help working out te solution?

1. I thought of deleting a fixed amount on rows each day, but the number or rows may be different as there may be more calendar events.
2. Previously, I had every row having a date. That doesn't look attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the script to delete all row entries that correspond to a date earlier than the current date (today). So assuming the sheet is ordered chronologically, it makes more sense for the loop to count the rows to be deleted from the top instead from the bottom.

That way you can use a single `deleteRows()` to remove a whole block at once.

### Solution:

```
function deleteRow_nedeles_plani() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Nedēļas plāni');
    var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-2;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
          var row = data[i][0];
          var date = new Date();
          var sheetDate = new Date(row);
          var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0300','yyyy-MM-dd')
          var rowDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0300', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
          Logger.log([rowDate.valueOf(), todayDate.valueOf()]);
          if (todayDate.valueOf() < rowDate.valueOf()) { break; }
    }

    sheet.deleteRows(3,i);
}
```

**Sample Input:**

[image]

**After Execution:**

[image]

Comment: Works. Execution time is even faster now with your solution since it now loops through the rows from the start, not end. Kudos!